# css, absolute positioning elements within relative positioning elements cluttering up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position my elements with absolute positioning within my relative div element. But it's cluttering up on eachother, as shown in this picture:

[image]

Probably not the best picture. But there's two identical divs on top of eachother.

I wanted the second copy of place itself under the first one, and so on if there were more. And thought relative was the way to do it. But it seems like I'm getting complications of the divs inside the relative container, if they have absolute positioning?

```
 <div class="industryoutter">
        <div class ="industryinnerleft">
        Agricultural Chemicals
        </div>
        <div class ="industryinnerright">
        C
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="industryoutter">
        <div class ="industryinnerleft">
        Agricultural Chemicals
        </div>
        <div class ="industryinnerright">
        C
        </div>
   </div>
```

css

```
.industryoutter {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    width: 210;
}

.industryinnerleft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}

.industryinnerright {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `width: 210` will do nothing since you omitted the unit (which is mandatory except for 0 lengths). Apart from that it is *totally unclear to me what you want to achieve*. Also, please understand that setting `position: absolute` on a block level element removes the behaviour that the element grabs as much width as it can get. Instead it shrinks to the minimum size required to hold its content. Next to that, please also note that your outer div will have a computed height of 0 since it only has children which have `position: absolute;`

Comment: Try adding height to your `.industryoutter`

Comment: Positioning like that isn't good practice, and it'll cause a **lot** of problems if you start using it for things like this. It's much better to use a simple float or a flex-box layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using absolute positioning for things like this is just bad practice, it makes everything harder. The easiest thing you could do is to just float `.industryinnerright` right, like:

```css
.industryoutter {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  width: 210px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.industryinnerright {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<div class="industryoutter">
  Agricultural Chemicals
  <span class="industryinnerright">C</span>
</div>
<div class="industryoutter">
  Agricultural Chemicals
  <span class="industryinnerright">C</span>
</div>
```

Make sure you add `overflow: hidden;` to `.industryoutter` so it will grow to fit its content's height. You also no longer need to wrap the left text in a div.

Comment: How are you getting this output? I mean i tried your code on fiddle it seemed to just print side by side. You better add a height to `industryoutter`, then it will work as expected.

Comment: @AakashThakur what do you mean? There is no need to add a set height in this case. There was one small error fixed now

Comment: Even with the updated code, you still aren't able to achieve the thing:https://jsfiddle.net/ztfeor7c/2/

Comment: @AakashThakur you still don't have the updated code -_- Check the HTML, there's no need for the first div

Comment: @AakashThakur what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry xD Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Just set a fixed height in the container to work with your inner divs.

```
.industryoutter {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    width: 210px;
    height: 50px;
}
```